# Mobile Safari Facebook Login Redirect Issue - Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, safari, facebook-javascript-sdk, mobile-safari

The Javascript SDK is working for every browser on my desktop, but I'm having issues with Safari on an iPhone.

Here's what happens:
 - I click Login
 - Facebook Oauth opens in a new window, and I successfully login
 - The Facebook Oauth Window closes, and the old window shows up
 - Rather than refresh the login page (as desktop browsers do), nothing happens...

So I'm successfully logged in, but the old page shows up.  The user thinks that they're not logged in.  I've seen similar issue son stack overflow but no answers.

Has anyone seen this or know of a solution?

```
 <html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
  <body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : <%= FACEBOOK_CONFIG['app_id'] %>, // App ID
        channelUrl : '//'+window.location.hostname+'/channel', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });
      // Additional initialization code here
      // whenever the user logs in, we refresh the page

      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
        setTimeout('document.location.reload()', 10);
      });

    };


    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
     }(document));
  </script>
```

Comment: If I could somehow get the browser to refresh after the redirect, that would work great as well...but despite adding a javascript time-out to refresh, just can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Just want to check you have added the URL to the 'mobile web' section of the Facebook app admin dashboard?

Comment: I did, and still had the issue, thanks though.

Comment: I had same issue and double-checking that url worked just fine for me

Comment: My app is having this problem intermittently. Did you ever find a solution?